# Google Maps not showing when I run my app for the first time without wifi (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

When I run my app for the first time (or when I clear cache) and I am not on a wifi connection the google map is not showing. If I connect to wifi the map will be shown also if I turn wifi off again on consecutive app starts. Is there a way to also get the map shown on first app start when one is on 4g f.e.?

edit:
looking at my log output both scenario's seem to more or less do the same. onMapReadyCallback is called in both. It just seems like somehow the map is not rendered in the case where I don't have wifi

Comment: share your code..

Comment: Did you restrict the usage of mobile data somehow on the device?

Comment: @Henry : not to my knowing. Everything else seems to be working just fine on mobile data. And it's really just first app start. Once I connect one time via wifi and turn wifi off after, the map tiles get rendered just fine on mobile data..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the map not being rendered is a device related issue. I've got a HUAWEI P8 Lite and map is not rendered on this phone. Same as I start the Uber app for first time, the map is simply not rendered.

I've tested the code on another device, MOTO G, and there to map is shown just fine.